# Where to get "UTF-8" string literal in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a constant instead of a string literal in this piece of code:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")
```

`"UTF-8"` appears in the code rather often, and would be much better to refer to some `static final` variable instead. Do you know where I can find such a variable in JDK?

BTW, on a second thought, such constants are bad design: [Public Static Literals ... Are Not a Solution for Data Duplication](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/07/06/public-static-literals.html)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1684040/3009).

Comment: Note: if you are already on Java 7, use [`Files.newBufferedWriter(Path path, Charset cs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) from NIO.

Comment: That's some really bad advice from your link. He wants you to make a wrapper class for every possible string constant you might use?

Answer (score 985, accepted):

In Java 1.7+, [java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) defines constants for `Charset` including `UTF_8`.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

...

StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
```

**For Android: minSdk 19**

Comment: do you use .toString() on that?

Comment: `.toString()` will work but the proper function is `.name()`. 99.9% toString is not the answer.

Comment: btw `.displayName()` will also work unless it is overridden for localization as intended.

Comment: You don't really need to call `name()` at all. You can directly pass the `Charset` object into the `InputStreamReader` constructor.

Comment: Note that in Andorid, this require API level 19+.

Comment: And there are other libs out there which do require a `String`, perhaps because of legacy reasons. In such cases, I keep a `Charset` object around, typically derived from `StandardCharsets`, and use `name()` if needed.

Comment: The result for `name()`, `toString()` and just putting `StandardCharsets.UTF-8` directly is all the same because `Charset.toString()` just calls `Charset.name()` and if you use `StandardCharsets.UTF-8` in a place where a String is expected `Charset.toString()` will be called automatically.

Comment: When I used only toString(), on Android6 it returned "java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]", definitely not what I wanted. Using .name() returned the correct value "UTF-8"

Answer (score 147):

Now I use `org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding.UTF_8` constant from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Comment: For those using Lang 3.0: `org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding.UTF_8`. (Note "lang3").

Comment: If you're using Java 1.7, see @Roger's answer below since it's part of the standard library.

Comment: P.S. "@Roger's answer below" is now @Roger's answer _above_. ☝

Comment: That class is deprecated since Java 7 introduce java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

Answer (score 73):

The [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library (which I'd highly recommend anyway, if you're doing work in Java) has a [`Charsets`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html) class with static fields like `Charsets.UTF_8`, `Charsets.UTF_16`, etc.

Since Java 7 you should just use `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets` instead for comparable constants.

Note that these constants aren't strings, they're actual `Charset` instances. All standard APIs that take a charset name also have an overload that take a `Charset` object which you should use instead.

Comment: So, should be Charsets.UTF_8.name()?

Comment: @kilaka Yeah use name() instead of getDisplayName() since name() is final and getDisplayName() is not

Comment: Bad idea to use third party code that's constantly modified, breaking backwards compatibility,  to accomplish something you can do with the standard SDK.

Comment: @Buffalo: Please read my answer again: it recommends using `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets` when possible, which is not third party code. Additionally, the Guava Charsets definitions are not "constantly modified" and AFAIK have never broken backwards compatibility, so I don't think your criticism is warranted.

Comment: We've had multiple issues when upgrading the Guava libraries.

Comment: @Buffalo: That's as it may be, but I doubt your issues had anything to do with the `Charsets` class. If you want to complain about Guava, that's fine, but this is not the place for those complaints.

Comment: Please do not include a multi-megabyte library to get one string constant.

Comment: "All standard APIs that take a charset name also have an overload that take a Charset object" is not quite true.  One example is `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`, which does not have an overload taking a `Charset` parameter.

Answer (score 51):

In case this page comes up in someones web search, as of Java 1.7 you can now use [java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) to get access to constant definitions of standard charsets.

Comment: I have been trying to use this but it does not seem to work. 'Charset.defaultCharset());' seems to work after including 'java.nio.charset.*' but I can't seem to explicitly refer to UTF8 when I am trying to use 'File.readAllLines'.

Comment: @Roger What seems to be the problem? 
From what I can see you can just call:
`Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path-to-some-file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, but it worked for me after changing something which I can't remember.

Comment: ^^^ You probably had to change the target platform in the IDE. If 1.6 was your latest JDK when you installed the IDE, it probably picked it as the default & kept it as the default long after you'd updated both the IDE and JDK themselves in-place.

Answer (score 10):

This constant is available (among others as: `UTF-16`, `US-ASCII`, etc.) in the class `org.apache.commons.codec.CharEncoding` as well.

Answer (score 9):

There are none (at least in the standard Java library). Character sets vary from platform to platform so there isn't a standard list of them in Java.

There are some 3rd party libraries which contain these constants though. One of these is Guava (Google core libraries): http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html

Comment: It took me a second to catch on to this... Guava's Charsets constants are (no surprise) Charsets, not Strings.  InputStreamReader has another constructor that takes a Charset rather than a string.  If you really need the string, it's e.g. Charsets.UTF_8.name().

Comment: Character sets do may vary from platform to platform, but UTF-8 is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: All charsets defined in `StandardCharsets` are guaranteed to exist in every Java implementation on every platform.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Charset.defaultCharset()` API or `file.encoding` property.

But if you want your own constant, you'll need to define it yourself.

Comment: The default charset is usually determinded by the OS and locale settings, I don't think there is any guarantee that it remains the same for multiple java invocations. So this is no replacement for a constant sepcifying "utf-8".

Answer (score 8):

In Java 1.7+

Do not use "UTF-8" string, instead use `Charset` type parameter:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

...

new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for Java/Android you can use the following constant:

```java
import com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util;

Util.UTF_8; // Charset
Util.UTF_8.name(); // String
```

Comment: it's removed from OkHttp, so next way is: `Charset.forName("UTF-8").name()` when you need support for lower Android than API 19+ otherwise you can use: `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()`

Answer (score 4):

Constant definitions for the standard. These
  charsets are guaranteed to be available on every implementation of the Java
  platform.  since 1.7

```
 package java.nio.charset;
 Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
```

Answer (score 3):

Class `org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding.UTF_8` is deprecated after Java 7 introduced `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`

- @see [JRE character encoding names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)
- @since 2.1
- @deprecated Java 7 introduced {@link java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets}, which defines these constants as
- {@link Charset} objects. Use {@link Charset#name()} to get the string values provided in this class.
- This class will be removed in a future release.