# Found reliance on default encoding

Tags: findbugs

I am getting below bug from FindBugs,

Found reliance on default encoding in MyClass.print(String): String.getBytes()

**Method**

```
protected void print (String str) {
{
private OutputStream outStream = null;
.....
outStream.write(str.getBytes());
.......
}
```

What is the error, and how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

There are different ways of encoding a String as bytes -- the charset determines that encoding.  If you don't specify a charset, as in your call to `str.getBytes()`, it uses the system default.

FindBugs is warning you about this because you should think about what encoding you want to use for your output.  If you're writing to a file, what are the readers of that file expecting?  It is safest if you can specify an explicit encoding for the file so you don't write it one way and read it another way.

To specify an explicit charset, use `str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`, for example.  UTF-8 is a good choice because it is always supported and can encode any character.

For example, `.properties` files are always ISO 8859-1 (i.e. Latin-1).  That's documented so there is no ambiguity around what encoding to use.

Comment: As an alternative to `Charset.forName("UFT-8")` Java 7 defines `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16066990/152061

Comment: If you have the opposite case (bytes -> string, not string -> bytes), use `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` instead of  `new String(bytes);`