# writeDataToFile(String) may fail to clean up java.io.Writer on checked exception in FindBugs

Tags: android, findbugs

I'm using FileWrite class to Write into a file.and its working fine. But FindBugs is pointing me a Minor issue in my code snippet.

**code snippet:**

```
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
        Date now = new Date();
        String fileName = formatter.format(now) + ".txt";
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Test");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, fileName);

            writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile, true);
            writer.append(text + "\n\n");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Findbug Report:**

OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION: Method may fail to clean up stream or resource
writeDataToFile(String) may fail to clean up java.io.Writer on checked exception

**In which line i'm getting this Error?**

```
  writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile, true);
```

Could some one please brief me what is this exactly? 
And how can we solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because of `writer.flush();`. This could lead to IOException since it  writes any buffered output to the underlying stream. If the exception occurs the writer won't be closed.

If its mandatory to flush in `finally{..}` then use dedicated `try{..} catch{..}` for each line as follows:

```
finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        try {
            writer.flush();                
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u:-),That issue is gone ,But in same line I got one more findbugs Warning Says "Found reliance on default encoding: new java.io.FileWriter(File, boolean)" .  Can u help me for this?

Comment: @kavie you can check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347435/found-reliance-on-default-encoding) for that

Comment: If I use String I can use some Default encoding methods,But here I'm passing File as first parameter right?

Comment: @kavie looks like its pointing to fact that simply using append will use default encoding. There is a way to change the encoding as shown in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132693/set-encoding-as-utf-8-for-a-filewriter). However you might need to do some extra work. I would recommend you to create new question for it if the link doesn't help.