# Verify class producing Test Anything Protocol (TAP)

Tags: java, tap

I'd like to write a unit test for a class that produces a [Test Anything Protocol (TAP)](https://testanything.org/) via [tap4j](http://tap4j.org/). How could I verify the result which is internally retrieved from [`TapProducer#dump(TestSet)`](http://tap4j.org/tap4j/apidocs/org/tap4j/producer/TapProducer.html#dump-org.tap4j.model.TestSet-)?

In addition to a bunch of predefined strings, I thought about something like [InstantTAP](http://instanttap.appspot.com/) to test against the specification, but locally. Any suggestions on libraries I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of solved this by using a tap4j [`Parser`](http://tap4j.org/tap4j/apidocs/org/tap4j/parser/Parser.html) which would throw a `ParserException` if the given string violates the specification:

```
Parser parser = new Tap13Parser( "UTF-8", true, true );
parser.parseTapStream( tapStream );
```

The three parameters are [defined](http://tap4j.org/tap4j/apidocs/org/tap4j/parser/Tap13Parser.html#Tap13Parser-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-) as follows:

> - `encoding` - Encoding. This will not matter when parsing sources that are already decoded (e.g. `String` or `Readable`), but it will be used in the `parseFile(java.io.File)` method (whether or not it is the right encoding for the `File` being parsed).
> - `enableSubtests` - Whether subtests are enabled or not
> - `planRequired` - flag that defines whether a plan is required or not

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6698354/3429133) question to see how to retrieve constants for encodings.