# Encoding CharsetNames for Charset.forName(String)

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a question about Charset.forName(String charsetName).  Is there a list of charsetNames I can refer to?  For example, for UTF-8, we use "utf8" for the charsetName.  What about WINDOWS-1252, GB18030, etc.?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html and the latest http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: Also there is a good discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684040/java-why-charset-names-are-not-constants

Answer (score 7):

```
Charset         Description

US-ASCII        Seven-bit ASCII, a.k.a. ISO646-US, a.k.a. the Basic Latin block of the Unicode character set
ISO-8859-1      ISO Latin Alphabet No. 1, a.k.a. ISO-LATIN-1
UTF-8           Eight-bit UCS Transformation Format
UTF-16BE        Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, big-endian byte order
UTF-16LE        Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, little-endian byte order
UTF-16          Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, byte order identified by an optional byte-order mark
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Answer (score 3):

The charset names in Java are platform dependent, there are only 6 constants in the [StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class.

To view the all charsets you should look at [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets). Check Preferred MIME Name and aliases columns.

Answer (score 2):

To list all character set installed in your JVM, you might use the following
code snippet (Java 8 SE or higher):

```
SortedMap<String, Charset> map = Charset.availableCharsets();
map.keySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

On my system, this lists around 170 character sets.

Answer (score 0):

The java Charset library is *required* to accept just a few basic encodings: ASCII, Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1), and a handful of UTF variants that you can see listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18762605/699305). That's a pretty useless list for any practical purposes, unless your scope is limited to Latin-1. In reality, Java classes can handle a large number of encodings that you can read about in the [Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) page. Quoting from it:

> The `java.io.InputStreamReader`, `java.io.OutputStreamWriter`, `java.lang.String` classes, and classes in the `java.nio.charset` package can convert between Unicode and a number of other character encodings. The supported encodings vary between different implementations of Java SE 8. The class description for `java.nio.charset.Charset` lists the encodings that any implementation of Java SE 8 is required to support.
>
> **JDK 8 for all platforms (Solaris, Linux, and Microsoft Windows) and JRE 8 for Solaris and Linux support all encodings shown on this page.** JRE 8 for Microsoft Windows may be installed as a complete international version or as a European languages version. [...]

The rest of [the page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) consists of an extensive table of encoding names and synonyms, which is what the OP was after all those years ago...