# Displaying Jtidy error/warning messages in a GUI JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtidy

I am writing a program that uses jtidy to clean up html from source code obtained from a URL. I want to display the errors and warnings in a GUI, in a JTextArea. How would I "reroute" the warnings from printing to stdout to the JTextArea? I've looked over the Jtidy API and don't see anything that does what I want. Anyone know how I can do this, or if it's even possible?

// testing jtidy options

```
public void test(String U) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    InputStream URLInputStream = new URL(U).openStream();
    File file = new File("test.html");
    FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

    tidy.setShowWarnings(true);
    tidy.setShowErrors(0);
    tidy.setSmartIndent(true);
    tidy.setMakeClean(true);
    tidy.setXHTML(true);
    Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(URLInputStream, fop);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming JTidy prints errors and warnings to stdout, you can just [temporarily change where `System.out` calls go](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29):

```
PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream myOutputStream = new PrintStream(baos);
System.setOut(myOutputStream);

// your JTidy code here

String capturedOutput = new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.setOut(originalOut);

// Send capturedOutput to a JTextArea
myTextArea.append(capturedOutput);
```

There is [an analogous method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29) if you need to do this for `System.err` instead/as well.

Comment: I tried, but the "StandardCharsets.UTF_8" part gives me an error and only the option to create a class with that name (in eclipse) do I need to import something, or is there a minor typo there?

Comment: It's part of Java 7. If you're not there yet, you can get by well enough omitting the charset argument entirely, though it's not best practice. Otherwise, pass `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` and catch the exception (which will never actually be thrown, in practice). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684040/java-why-charset-names-are-not-constants